# Aggregation framework not working properly in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have `HistorySchema` collection and has doc as

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("60edb556ec3ad87aaa09bcc4"),
    billID: ObjectId("60edb556ec3ad87aaa09bcc3"),
    createdAt: "2021-07-13T15:46:30.569Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-07-13T15:46:30.569Z"
}
```

`BillSchema` collection as

```
{
   _id: ObjectId"60edb556ec3ad87aaa09bcc3",
   createdAt: "2021-07-13T15:46:30.485+00:00",
   updatedAt: "2021-07-13T15:46:30.485+00:00"
}
```

Now when I aggregate history with bill as

```
const history = await history.aggregate([
                {$lookup: {
                    from: "BillSchema",
                    localField: "billID",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "billData"
                }},
            ])
```

it returns history data but billData is always empty array as

```
[
   {
        "_id": "60edb556ec3ad87aaa09bcc4",
        "billID": "60edb556ec3ad87aaa09bcc3",
        "createdAt": "2021-07-13T15:46:30.569Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-13T15:46:30.569Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "billData": []
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your history collections's billId in string and bill collection billId is in integer.
SO you need to convert

```
db.history.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "billID": {
        $toInt: "$billID"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bill",
      localField: "billID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "billData"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bSTluPb1eK3)**

Comment: Sorry, actually I made mistake while posting question. Actually it was mongodb db objected and all the id is in ObjectId format which is string. Now I have updated the post, please have a look. What is the issue?

Comment: I dont face any issue there https://mongoplayground.net/p/aDbYVcsFu8U

Comment: While exporting model I have exported as ```'export default mongoose.model("BillSchema", BillSchema);'``` and in mongodb atlas bill collection is saved as ```'billschemas'``` in plural form. While lookup, I changed BillSchema name to ```billschemas``` now its working. Anyway thank you for your effort.